# Enterprise Architect - TFS - associate with work item

Tags: tfs, enterprise-architect

Situation:
Enterprise Architect project (.eap) integrated in TFS repository. User checks-out some package, makes a change and than performs a check-in.

Question:
Does anybody know if it is possible to associate a check-in operation with a TFS work item in the EA itself somehow?

Comment: In general, you should be able to associate a given work item with a check-in via the check-in under Related Work Items (Add Work Item by ID).  Does this not work for you?

Comment: In EA _itself_? I am affraid I don't see there.

Comment: Have you tried making a connection to a workitem mandatory? If you're lucky there will be a tsf popup asking to select a workitem. If you're not then it will refuse the checkin altogether.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Enterprise Architect appears to be a third-party IDE. Check-in policies only work within Visual Studio.

Comment: Exactly, when you commit from EA, any check-in policy is bypassed. That's better then nothing, but it would be much nicer to be able to associate with a work item, to fit in this type of policy.

Comment: I'm not familiar with EA, but if there is no option to relate a work item during checkin in EA, you may consider adding a changeset link manually in your work item. Otherwise, you may check on EA side to see whether it can customize an extension to relate a work item.

Comment: I think you better send in a feature request instead of creating your own solution (which should be possible)